# Is possible to keep origin request IP after proxying pass?

Tags: proxy, google-compute-engine

I have a structure on GCE like this (I will use LB for Network Loading Balancer):

client request -> LB -> Apache Web Server On Instance -> Proxy to Another LB (request arrived to another instance).

That's the request flow. Is it possible to log origin request address to the final instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options, depending on how you want to configure your systems.

One option is to [configure Apache to set the X-Forwarded-For header](http://www.techstacks.com/howto/log-client-ip-and-xforwardedfor-ip-in-apache.html), and the target system would then need to log that header as the source IP.

Another option is to set the [canIpForward](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#canipforward) property on your Apache server, [configure a routing rule on the target instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#instancerouting) to send its internet traffic via the Apache server, and configure the Apache server for transparent load-balancing (possibly via iptables rewrite rules -- see [this page](https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/admin/transparent-proxy.en.html) for a similar setup for Apache Traffic Server).

Depending on what you want to use the Apache server for, you might also want to consider using the [GCE HTTP load-balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/), which scales to [1 million qps](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2013/11/compute-engine-load-balancing-hits-1-million-requests-per-second.html).